# EzPublish - eZUser fetch on personal field

Tags: php, ezpublish

I would like to fetch an user on a personal field. With eZUser class, we can make fetchByName or fetchByEmail, but my field is specific (mdcode). How can i do that ?

I tried something with eZPersistentObject but it doesn't want to work with a specific field. I  can make the same than fetchByEmail or fetchByName but not with my own field...

Someone can help me ?

Comment: ... It was easy, a simple fetch with attribute filter. It was not the good way to use ezUser...

Answer (score 0):

Please use like below,

User should be logged.

{**$logged_user_email = $logged_user.contentobject.data_map.compte_utilisateur.content.email**}